# System.FormatException in correct format C#

Tags: c#

I am making a dll to use some functions that are missing in c# such as python's eval function ( which is definatly awsome ) here is the code of my eval class

```
public class EvalMath
    {
        public double result { get; private set; }

        private delegate double Operation(double x, double y);




        public EvalMath()
        {


        }
        private static string Reverse(string s)
        {
            char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charArray);
            return new string(charArray);
        }

        public double Eval(string operation)
        {
            operation = Reverse(operation);

            Operation op = null;
            if (operation == null) throw new EvalArgumentException();
            string integer1_r = "";
            foreach (char chr in operation)
            {
                if(chr == '+' || chr == '-' || chr == '*' || chr == '/')
                {
                    string integer = operation.Substring(0, operation.IndexOf(chr));

                    string integer1 = operation.Substring(operation.IndexOf(chr) + 1);
                    if(integer1.Contains("+") || integer1.Contains("-") || integer1.Contains("*") || integer1.Contains("/"))  integer1_r = Eval(integer.ToString()).ToString();
                    switch (chr)
                    {
                        case '+':
                            op = (x, y) => x + y;
                            break;
                        case '-':
                            op = (x, y) => x - y;
                            break;
                        case '*':
                            op = (x, y) => x * y;
                            break;
                        case '/':
                            op = (x, y) => x / y;
                            break;
                    }
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(integer + " " + integer1_r); // for debug
                    result = op(Convert.ToDouble(integer), Convert.ToDouble(integer1_r));

                    return result;
                }


            }
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
```

and i am trying this code to test it

```
EvalMath e = new EvalMath();
double res = e.Eval("3+3");

Console.ReadLine();
```

but whenever i try to run the code it just gies me a System.FormatException in this line

```
  double res = e.Eval("3+3");
```

Comment: i know i was just testing Can you just find the problem please

Comment: Why you don't use the `debbuger`?? it will show you exactly the line that break and the reason. the format exception is not in the line you wrote, it somewhere inside that functino...

Comment: Yeah but it shows it on that line.... so i cannot figure out where it throws the error

Comment: I strongly suspect that the exception shows more stack frames than just `Eval`. You should look carefully at the stack trace. But even if you can't do that, you can step through the `Eval` method line by line.

Comment: Make sure that 'integer1_r' as well as 'integer' only contains a number in this line: 'result = op(Convert.ToDouble(integer), Convert.ToDouble(integer1_r));' Could be that you're trying to convert a non-numerical value to a double.

Comment: ok so i got the problem When i say  `string integer1 = operation.Substring(operation.IndexOf(chr) + 1);
                    if(integer1.Contains("+") || integer1.Contains("-") || integer1.Contains("*") || integer1.Contains("/"))  integer1_r = Eval(integer.ToString()).ToString();` the program tries to eval "2" alone in "2+2" but when i enter "2+2+2" it didnt give me an error

Comment: Cool, but to @DaisyShipton 's point: step through it with the debugger and see what values those variables contain.

Comment: OK nvm i did what you said i accidently forgot to add 1 to end of  "integer" so it becomes "integer1" and the program overwrites "integer" and so integer1_r becomes null and says FormatException

Comment: I don't want to ruin your day, but you can simply install the microsofts scripting package from https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples

Comment: Console.WriteLine(new System.Data.DataTable().Compute("3+3", ""));

Answer (score 0):

Added one line in your code. You forgot to set integer1_r value in case of integer1 doesn't contain any operator. Following line is added in your code.

```
else integer1_r = integer1;
```

Following is the complete code.

```
public class EvalMath
{
    public double result { get; private set; }

    private delegate double Operation(double x, double y);

    public EvalMath()
    {

    }
    private static string Reverse(string s)
    {
        char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);
        return new string(charArray);
    }

    public double Eval(string operation)
    {
        operation = Reverse(operation);

        Operation op = null;
        if (operation == null) throw new EvalArgumentException();
        string integer1_r = "";
        foreach (char chr in operation)
        {
            if(chr == '+' || chr == '-' || chr == '*' || chr == '/')
            {
                string integer = operation.Substring(0, operation.IndexOf(chr));

                string integer1 = operation.Substring(operation.IndexOf(chr) + 1);
                if(integer1.Contains("+") || integer1.Contains("-") || integer1.Contains("*") || integer1.Contains("/"))  integer1_r = Eval(integer.ToString()).ToString();
                else integer1_r = integer1;

                switch (chr)
                {
                    case '+':
                        op = (x, y) => x + y;
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        op = (x, y) => x - y;
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        op = (x, y) => x * y;
                        break;
                    case '/':
                        op = (x, y) => x / y;
                        break;
                }
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(integer + " " + integer1_r); // for debug
                result = op(Convert.ToDouble(integer), Convert.ToDouble(integer1_r));

                return result;
            }


        }
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```